# Namespace could not be found

Tags: c#

It can be seen and compiled inside the same file it is in inside the same project, the file is called default.aspx.cs.

However when I try to include the namespace in another file of the same project using the using DBConnStrings; statement ->  I keep getting the compiler error "The type or namespace name 'DBConnStrings' could not be found".

The Code in the file which compiles called default.aspx.cs is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using DBConnStrings;

namespace DBConnStrings
{
    public class GlobalStrings
    {
        public static string carSalesDBConnString = 
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ToString();
    }
}

public void BindManu()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new 
    SqlConnection(GlobalStrings.carSalesDBConnString); // Connect to Carsales database 
    conn.Open();
    // .....
}
```

The other files can not see this namespace although they are in the same project.

How do I make them see it?

Comment: How can you add a method outside of the class/namespace ?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any syntax errors in your file - start by formatting your code properly (ctrl+k, ctrl+d)

Comment: Your `BindManu` method should be inside a class (which would be inside a namespace)

Comment: All I am really trying to do is have a global string so I can connect to the database from any file in the project, so my idea was to put it inside a class inside a namespace and include that namespace in all the files of the project. This saves me alot of coding and is good programming practice. Unfortunately the other files do not recognise this namespace which is inside another file in the project.

Comment: People it would be most helpful if you can just answer the question and not criticize things that have nothing to do with it. My BindManu method works perfectly and is already inside a class in the default page Rufus. Please stick to and answer the question only, do not sidetrack. Thanks.

Comment: The exact compiler error is this in a different file of the same project: "The type or namespace name 'DBConnStrings' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I am not missing a using directive as the statement which generates the error is -> using DBConnStrings; Therefore it wants an assembly reference meaning it cant see the namespace I wrote. One way would be to write up a service and put it in a dll and include it in the assembly reference but I am hoping there would be an easier way for this file to be able to see the namespace. Same project.

Comment: Why not to use `App.config` or `Web.config` to keep that string?

Comment: Web.Config is already used. It is in XML we are talking about namespaces here. Web.Config has the database connection string but one must use the ToString() method on it to convert it to a C# string as I do in this code. Once again your comment is a bit off topic Stranger.

Comment: Rufus, BindManu is inside a class but I did not give you all the full code. I only gave the important bits. The question is why was it not being recognised as a namespace in the other files of the project. My correct answer is below. The reason has to do with project folders. Best thing is to include the namespace in a separate class file of the project. That is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd suggest to put the method `BindManu` into the class, because I can't imagine this would work like that.

But to your problem: You have to specify the whole namespace. That means, if the file with the `DBConnStrings` namespace is in the folder *test*, you have to use `using test.DBConnStrings` to import the namespace. You should name the namespace like that as well to avoid confusion (`namespace test.DBConnStrings`).

But you actually don't have to specify the whole path, just the path *within* the project. That means, if your class is in *C:\Users\Foo\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\BlaProject\DirectoryA\DirectoryB\MyClass* with the project located in *C:\Users\Foo\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\BlaProject*, your namespace would be *BlaProject.DirectoryA.DirectoryB*. If the file your using isn't in your project folder, then you have to add a reference and use the path within the other project as above (but with another project name, obviously). If you want to add references,  open the *Solution Explorer*, right click onto *References*, select *add Reference*, and select the reference to the project.

---

If you don't want to struggle with all that you can let vs do it for you. Simply type in the class you want from the other namespace, it will be marked as an error, click onto the lightbulb and select something like *add using reference*.

Furthermore, if you want to add a class to your project, don't do it with the explorer - simply right click onto the folder from your project you want to add the class to in your *Solution Explorer*, select *Add*, then *New Item*. In the popup select *class* and type in your name for the class. That's it!

Comment: I think you are coming close to the correct answer. I put my project under Visual Studio 2012 \ Projects\ Carsales Website folder however all my code files are in C\Carsales Website folder. Do I have to specify the full path like C\CarSales Website.DBConnStrings ?

Comment: My project file exists in this directory: Documents \ Visual Studio 2012 \ Projects \ Carsales Website. My actual code files exist in this Directory: C:\Carsales Website. So what do I need to do exactly if you can provide further help. Thanks.